# Multiplexer CD74HC4051, connections and parameters

Tags: multiplexer

I'm testing a multiplexer from Texas Instruments, below is shown the cabling I've done. But varying the select pins(9,10,11) has no effect, nothing happens. The LED always stays on.
Vcc is 5v connected to Arduino board.

What could I have done wrong?
Do I need to put in some resistors?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you actually connected the chip that way (and assuming the minus of the supply has an unseen connection to GND), you will need to procure a new chip before proceeding. GND must never go more positive than the E (or any other) control input by more than a few hundred mV.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming + is +5 volts with respect to ground. Then you need to tie 6,7,8 to ground. Put a 150 ohm from pin 3 to the LED, and tie the LED to ground, not -. Then the LED should light with all control lines high.

Also, make sure the ground on this circuit is tied to Arduino ground.

Finally, the control lines must go to 5 volts. A 3.3 volt output is not guaranteed to work. See http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4051.pdf Table 7, Vih.

Answer (score 0):

You either messed up your sketch, or you really tied both VCC and GND to a positive voltage. Right now, you are just using your IC as an expensive wire. And yes, you should use a resistor on that LED.

Comment: I'll repost the sketch, I've draw the connections inverted